# Does RabbitMQ serialize on disk every inbound message?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am evaluating RabbitMQ as an asynchronous middle-tier for my web application. My concern is that it will write to disk every single message it receives, as a consistency model. Is that true or does it optimize the queue in memory and serializes it to disk from time to time ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mark messages to be persistent or transient, and configure queues to be durable or not. If a message is transient, or is sent to a non-durable queue, it need never be written to disk at all.

For a persistent message sent to a durable queue, the message will only be written to disk if it can't be delivered immediately. At least, that's what i infer from the way that [publisher confirms](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/) work: a confirm is an indication that a message has been safely accepted by the RabbitMQ broker, and that occurs when *either* the message is written to disk, *or* it is passed to a consumer.

There is also an aside in the [second part of the tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) which mentions that:

> Also, RabbitMQ doesn't do `fsync(2)` for every message -- it may be just saved to cache and not really written to the disk.